# ImageMagick server requirements

Tags: php, mysql, hardware, imagemagick

I'm in the process of building a simple website, or to be more precise a simple component *for* a website that adds a watermark to an image, creates a few different size images, and overlays it onto a few products. These edits will be made every time someone queries an image in a certain directory on the server.

I know this can all be done with imagemagick, my only concern is that the whole website will grind to a halt every time someone views their image for the first time (after the edit's been made once, the database is updated to get the edited version every time a user accesses it).

The website isn't hosted yet, for the time being I'm testing on XAMPP, but I figured for this I'm going to need a virtual or dedicated server, I just need some advice on what sort of hardware specs I ought to be looking at. I doubt more than 2 or 3 people will be viewing photos at any one time, but at a guess I need to be sure that the server can handle up to 10 or so and still be functional.

Hope someone can advise on this, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For Imageprocessing you need some CPU Power. If the Images are large they will also consume memory. But I think you should in any case work with caching. I don't know your application but certainly there are possibilities to cache images which are rendered once into the filesystem.